# Is there a way to call on just the content of a Page without actually using that Page?

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, get-template-part

The question sounds weird i know, but what i'm trying to do is add a gravity form into a template that i made.

But all of their tutorials seem to be more along the lines of adding a form to a page and not so much to a template.

So the idea was to use a get_content() from a specific Page that i created (called "Form" in this case) put that into it's own content-form.php file and then call a get_template_part() into the section of my template where i need it in.

First off, is this too much abstraction? If it's just better to somehow call the form from this specific Form Page into my template of choice i'll do that but i'm just not sure how to go about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Gravity Forms provides a shortcode -- `[form]`, IIRC.  You could consider adding something like `do_shortcode( '[form id="1"]' );` to your template. (Assuming that the form you want had the ID `1`, of course.)

Comment: @ChipBennett I haven't tried anything yet other than creating the page because i didn't really know what to do.

Comment: @PatJ Please post your above comment as an answer - because it most probably **is** the answer.

Comment: Done -- though I think SeekingCharlie has the better answer, which uses a GravityForms function rather than `do_shortcode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put something like the following into your template file where you want the form to appear (example of a form called Contact Us):

```
gravity_form('Contact Us', false, false, false, '', false);
```

For more info on the false etc, see here: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Embedding_A_Form

Comment: @kaiser, thank you for sharing that link, and snippet both solved my problem.

Comment: @MARS It wasn't me, but "SeekingCharlie". I just edited the answer. And please mark the answer as solved (check mark below voting arrows) if that solved your problem.

Comment: @SeekingCharlie thanks for the answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms provides a shortcode -- `[form]`, IIRC. You could consider adding something like `do_shortcode( '[form id="1"]' );` to your template. (Assuming that the form you want had the ID 1, of course.)